# Wordpress scroll down arrow to a section of page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

Does anyone know how to put an arrow that scrolls down to another section of the page in wordpress. This arrow will be located at the homepage header and once the user sees it they click it to scroll down to the next section of the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is called "anchors".

Link:

```
<a href="#section_at_footer">Go to footer</a>
```

Section should contain

```
<div id="section_at_footer" name="section_at_footer"></div>
```

or

```
<span id="section_at_footer" name="section_at_footer"></span>
```

or any tag with this name="section_at_footer" attribute.

Comment: Just adding here : This solution jumps to the target - if you want a scroll, there are numerous ways to do it, such as javascript or plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow in header Should be a link:

```
<a href="#NEXT_SECTION">Read more</a>
```

Section should contain:

```
<section id="NEXT_SECTION"></section>
```

For smooth scrolling it requires javascript,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 500);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
});
```